# Filtering data in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I drag an drop a simple query without any criteria in a form.
I want to filter data (like FamilyName) via textbox in form through OnChange event.
Here the question: how can i filter query data with value of textbox?

Answer (score 1):

If your query now appears as a subform in your form, use the *MasterLinkFields* and *ChildLinkFields* properties of that subform *control*:

- As *MasterLinkFields*: [NameOfYourTextbox]
- As *ChildLinkFields*: [NameOfFieldInQueryToFilterWithValueOfYourTextbox]

Answer (score 0):

ON the After Update event of the textbox, you can set the record/row source of the query and/or subsform. You'll have to use vba to do this, but its a relatively simple task. Without any examples I can only give you the high level answer.